# Getting error while parsing the the JSON data into android

Tags: android, json

> i am getting this error

```
Error in parsing Dataorg.json.JSONException: Value ["AACHI"] at 0 of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Process: info.androidhive.materialdesign, PID: 18373
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

this is my json data that i am trying to parse.`[["AACHI"],["AJAY COMPANY"],["ALL OUT"],["AMBICA"],["AMICO PRODUCTS"],["AMUL"],["ANAND BHOG PRODUCTS"],["ANNAPURNA"],["ANOOS PRODUCTS"],["ARVIND LABORATORIES "],["ASWINI PHARMACEUTICALS"],["ATTK PRODUCTS"],["AVA"],["BAJAJ PRODUCTS "],["BAMBINO"],["BANJARAS PRODUCTS"],["BHAGAYALAKSHIMI PRODUCTS"],["BRITANNIA"],["cadbury"]]

> this is my code snippet to parse the json data.

```
 class DownloadJson extends AsyncTask {

    Activity context;
    ListView myListView;

    private  ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    public DownloadJson(Activity context, ListView myListView) {
        this.myListView = myListView;
        this.context = context;

    }

    public DownloadJson() {

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        this.dialog.setMessage("Please wait");
        this.dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        super.onCancelled();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
        String result = null;
        InputStream isr = null;
        String imageId = null;
        String ip = "http://ganarajsshetti.tk/mobileapp/selectjson.php/";
        try {

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(ip);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            isr = httpEntity.getContent();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http Connection" + e.toString());

        }
        // converting response to string
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            isr.close();
            result = sb.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in Converting Data" + e.toString());
        }

        // parse JSON data

        try {

            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
            strListView = new String[jsonArray.length()];
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
               JSONObject json_data = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                strListView[i] = json_data.getString("Num_Rows");

                System.out.println("--------------"+json_data.getString("Num_Rows"));

                Log.e("ACK_tag", "DATA" + strListView[i]);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in parsing Data" + e.toString());
        }

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
        //objAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,R.layout.vendorwithimage,R.id.venderdescrip,strListView);
        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
        callCustomAdaper(context);


    }
}
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (task.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING)
        task.cancel(true);
    if (task.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING)
        task.cancel(true);

}
```

`

Comment: There is no jsonobject in your json. Read more about json

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: Is that even valid JSON? It could be valid, but in any case it is quite strange. Anyway without a specific error message nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: the json is valid, but its not cool

Comment: "Error in parsing Dataorg.json.JSONException: Value ["AACHI"] at 0 of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject" this is the error i am getting

Comment: @VidyadharM see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by changing the lines

```
JSONObject json_data = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
strListView[i] = json_data.getString("Num_Rows");
```

to

```
JSONArray innerJsonArray = jsonArray.getJSONArray(i);
strListView[0] = json_data.get(0);
```

Comment: @kaveesh if you are asking me then...I don't know, It was present in the code snippet asked by Vidyadhar M but in the JSON it is not used as key anywhere so I have asked him to modify the code

Answer (score 2):

Its json array of arrays. It is like a 2D array.

```
JsonArray jsonarray= new JsonArray(json);
 for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
  strListView[i] = jsonarray.getJsonArray(i);


}
```

Link Source:https://www.json.com/json-array

Answer (score 1):

JSONObject json_data = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

Here ' jsonArray' contains array object not json object. 
So you have to change that to JsonArray

```
  JSONArray jsonArrayElement = jsonArray.getJSONArray(0);
```

And also this json is valid but not conventional or useful..!!

Check more information for json [here](http://json.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this. working fine

```
String json = "[[\"AACHI\"],[\"AJAY COMPANY\"],[\"ALL OUT\"],[\"AMBICA\"],[\"AMICO PRODUCTS\"],[\"AMUL\"],[\"ANAND BHOG PRODUCTS\"],[\"ANNAPURNA\"],[\"ANOOS PRODUCTS\"],[\"ARVIND LABORATORIES \"],[\"ASWINI PHARMACEUTICALS\"],[\"ATTK PRODUCTS\"],[\"AVA\"],[\"BAJAJ PRODUCTS \"],[\"BAMBINO\"],[\"BANJARAS PRODUCTS\"],[\"BHAGAYALAKSHIMI PRODUCTS\"],[\"BRITANNIA\"],[\"cadbury\"]]";
     try {
        JSONArray jsAr = new JSONArray(json);
        String job="";
        for(int i=0;i<jsAr.length();i++)
        {
            JSONArray js1 = jsAr.getJSONArray(i);
            job += js1.getString(0);

        }
        Toast.makeText(this,job,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

        Toast.makeText(this,"Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```